Noise in audio project with ESP32
I built a very simple web radio based on a PCM5202 module (purple with 3.5mm output jack), an ESP32, and this github project. Here is the schematics (forgive the crudeness)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab



(Some parts of the soldering job needs cleaning I know. It was clean before I tried so many things...)
The audio amp is a very simple analog stereo amp box with volume, bass and tone controls. The three other components are all on the same perfboard.
It works surprisingly well, except that the ESP induces crackling sound which I'm pretty sure comes from WiFi activity.
Here's what I tried so far with no success:

Use another 12v SMPS: it's either worse or marginally better. Never goes away.
Use a linear 12v adapter: same noise, except of course I get 60 Hz hum along with it.
Put the components away from each other, especially from the wifi antenna
Add a 1000µF filter cap to the 12v rail
Add a 0.1µF bypass cap to the DAC (didn't help but I left it there)
Replace the 12v SMPS by quality 19v SMPS, and add a 12v buck converter to feed into the audio amp
Put a 10k resistor between the DAC's BCK pin and GND, as per this answer.
Remove the ground wire from the 12v SMPS to the perfboard (which connects the buck converter, the ESP32 and the DAC module together). It's MUCH worse.
Remove the ground line from the DAC output to the amp.
Try to shield the various modules with aluminium foil.

Here's what works:

The noise COMPLETELY goes away if I power the audio amp from a seperate 12v SMPS.
Disconnecting the whole analog output from the DAC. Of course there's no audio, but there's no crackling sound either.
Use headphones instead of the audio amp. Disconnect the analog lines between the amp and the DAC, but leave the amp powered. Audio is perfect through the headphones.

I'm completely lost right now. I have no idea what to try next. I could just use two separate power supplies and be done with it but then I wouldn't learn anything.
Any clue?

Is this an actual board you've designed or one of those purple little DAC modules I find online that at first glance has the analog and digital grounds all connected together ?

How are connected your ground signals together ? Ground loops are known to cause issues in audio projects. If using 2 12V SMPS solves the issue, it could be so by breaking a wired ground loop.

@unimportant yes it is a purple module with a 3.5mm output Jack.

@mathieu g. Yes they are all tied together. There is a barrel jack for the 12v input where a wire for gnd goes to the amp, then another wire for gnd goes to the perfboard. A ground loop problem seems reasonable but I don't know how to test for it.

Then your options are limited. Normally you'd lay out the board with separate digital and analog grounds (that's why the dac chip has analog and digital ground pins) and tie them together in a single place in such a way digital currents don't travel trough the analog ground. But with a premade module that ties all grounds together you don't have that option. Perhaps look into isolated DC-DC modules to provide 2 isolated supplies from a single supply...

It seems the audio amp receives two grounds: the one from the jack barrel and the one from the DAC that are probably the exact same signals. This is a ground loop. Try to increase (longer wires far from each other)/decrease (shorter wire close together) the surface delimited by the ground wire forming the loop to see if it has any effect. I am just guessing. Add pictures of your setup for us to help.

@Unimportant Interesting. I'll poke the DAC module around and try a few things with it.

@MathieuG. Alright I'll try a few things with wire lengths and placement. I'll also post a picture of the actual project later today.

@MathieuG. I added some pictures of the actual project. I tried to move wires and components around and no improvement. I also tried some primitive shielding. I took another shot at removing the ground line between the DAC and the amp. Still no dice.

@Unimportant I's the purple module indeed. I did check and all the ground points are tied together. I did try to remove the ground line from the 12v SMPS to the buck converter and unsurprisingly the audio became noisy as heck, but also the same crackling sound was still there.

I've updated the list of things that works and the list of things that don't. Thanks for your help guys, I really appreciate it.

If putting the amp on a separate isolated power supply resolves the issue, then a possible solution would be to replace the 3.3V buck with a 3.3V isolated converter.

@user1850479 nice, makes sense. Any suggestions for a cheap popular one?

Wow it looks like isolated DC-DC converters aren't cheap! I've ordered a cheaper stereo GLI (ground loop isolator). I'll post back once I receive and test it.

The problem of this design is a ground loop. I bought a cheap 5$ stereo GLI (ground loop isolator) off AliExpress and the noise is mostly gone.
Thanks to @Mathieu G., @Unimportant and @user1850479 for their help in the question's comments.
